# Git Bash find exec recursively on folders and files containing spaces

Tags: find, git-bash, webp

**Question:** In Git Bash on windows, how would you run the following in a way that it will also search folders with spaces in the name, and execute on files with spaces in the name?

`$ find ./ -type f -name '*.png' -exec sh -c 'cwebp -q 75 $1 -o "${1%.png}.webp"' _ {} \;`

**Context** I'm running Git Bash on windows, trying to execute a command on all found .png files to convert them to .webp format.  It works for all files without spaces in the path, but it's failing to find files with spaces in the filename or files within folders that have spaces in the folder name.
A few considerations:

1. I have many, many levels of folders to iterate through, and I can't run this command separately for each. I really need the recursion to work.
2. I cannot change the folder names; it will break other dependencies (nor did I create the folder or filenames originally, so cut me some slack!)
3. I arrived here by following the suggestions from this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/07/converting-images-to-webp/
4. the program, to my knowledge, doesn't ship with any built-in recursive command... golly that'd be handy

Any help you can provide will be appreciated. Thanks!